# Why is video streaming so slow from my site?

Tags: php, html, flash

I have some .flv files on my site and I've been using JWplayer to embed them into my webpages. The embedding looks like this:

```
<embed
flashvars="file=/tmp/<?php echo $row["location"]; ?>&autostart=true"
allowfullscreen="true"
allowscripaccess="always"
id="player1"
name="player1"
src="/jwplayer/player.swf"
width="500"
height="350"
/>
```

The file is coming from directory tmp and is is saved in a format *.flv. Recently, I have been noticing really slow streaming. The video will stop almost every 5 seconds. This is happening on multiple computers on multiple networks and I'm not having the same problem on different sites (i.e. youtube). I'm hosting the site through Yahoo Small Business and I have a lot of video files in the tmp directory.

Could anyone recommend me a way to allow my videos to be streamed faster?

Comment: This is almost certainly a hosting problem, not a programming problem.  As such, I've voted to move it to the appropriate forum.

Comment: Maybe your server's internet connection is too slow and overloads because of many views.
What is you server's internet s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with configuration of JWplayer, most likely it's network issue, most hosting providers are not optimised for media streaming, for that purposes you have to use  Content Delivery Network also known as CDN like [akamai](http://www.akamai.com/), [edgecast](http://www.edgecast.com/services/streaming/) or [maxcdn](http://www.maxcdn.com/)

Comment: I'm not that good with website management yet, which do you think would be the best for me to use, that is, which is the easiest to use? Also, will it be hard to transfer everything over to a CDN?

Comment: To piggy-back on the off-loading suggestion, you might also consider that the Longtail people have a [media hosting solution](http://www.longtailvideo.com/bits-on-the-run/) of their own.

Comment: @Mike, most CDN providers support content mirroring, usually you have to change your media url from http://mydomain.com/media/file.flv to something like http://mydomain.com.cdnprovider.net/media/file.flv or bind it via DNS to http://cdn.mydomain.com/media/file.flv